# Ionic. Bug with layout on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to start develop mobile apps with Ionic, but I have some troubles with layout on my Android device.

Text and borders are broken on my side bar.

[image: screenshot]

My device is HTC desire 600 dual sim, android version 4.1.2.
Can anyone tell me what's the reason of strange rendering and what to do?